# Can I play sound from this class into another class and control it from the other class

Tags: java

http://pastie.org/1887099

I want to be able to control this sound from another class via a JButton from a different class.

Comment: Congratulations, that's a fine and obtainable goal.

Comment: How would i go about doing this?

Comment: Is that even relevant???

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's say your class playing a sound is named SoundClass, and your class containing a button is named ButtonClass.

- Pass a reference for the SoundClass object to the the ButtonClass object when initializing the ButtonClass object.
- In the ButtonClass initialization, record the SoundClass object in a private attribute of type SoundClass.
- In the button action listener, use the SoundClass reference to play the sound by calling the appropriate method.

This is a basic application of OOP and separation of concerns.